# Calculate the needed space for a raster pyramid with QGIS

Tags: raster, image-pyramids

How can I calculate (or where can I find information to calculate) the required disk space for a raster map of 36GB which should be in a pyramid of 10 levels ?

Comment: In what GIS Software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, assuming a "four tiles merged into one" tiling scheme, each pyramid level should be one quarter the previous level.  In practice, things are not so concrete, since compression algorithms are generally in use within the base raster, and the compression ratio will change (for the worse, initially, then for the better). 
For your base level of 36Gb, you'll see a pyramid of roughly 12 Gb.

```
    9000 + 2250 + 562 + 141 + 35 + 9 + 2 + 1 + 0 + 0 = 12000 Mb
```

If you use a different compression algorithm in the pyramid, then anything goes.

Comment: As demonstrated here, the sum of the series approaches one third (33% increase)